# Redirect to different App view directory from urls.py

Tags: django, wagtail

I have URL definitions in my wagtail blog's app directory(`blog/urls.py`), and I would like to reference a view in my search app directory (`search/views.py`). The current URL definition is `url(r'^search/$', search, name='search')`. I don't want to duplicate common search views in every app's views file. How do I format the URL in my blog app to use the search view in search/views.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the blog app and search app are in the same level in project path directory,
You can use relative import like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns 
from search.views import search

urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^search$', search ,  name='search'),

)
```

Comment: @Cleverlemming If it worked,then you should accept my answer.